# mvn clean install + java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven-3

Got next error with maven using console:

```
d:\projects.perforce\FOTradeCapture\branches\evb-dev>mvn clean install
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [15:27:13]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [15:27:13]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: [15:27:13].  Program will exit.
```

Maven was successfully installed and worked for some period of time.

Thanks for ideas.
==============================================================================
Aditional info:

```
d:\projects.perforce\FOTradeCapture\branches\evb-dev>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.1 (r1038046; 2010-11-23 12:58:32+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_23
Java home: c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

Comment: What does mvn -version return?

Comment: At what point does the exception come - which phase/goal - can you post the relevant pom snippet which causes this?  Do you have a maven exec plugin in your pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had corrupted MAVEN_OPTS in Environment Variables.
I've changed maven memory settings and it stopped to work only after machine restart (on the next day).

Answer (score 0):

you must check pom.xml of your project and be sure that mainClass tag on pom.xml

reference to your project's class that contain main(String[] args) method.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <mainClass>ir.codepress.MainApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```